# Connecting redux store to nextjs layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I've got a simple nextjs layout:

```
export default class AppLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Header />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

I've been trying to wrap it with a redux store:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './header'
import Footer from './footer'
import Page from './page';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AppLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Header />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </>
        )
    }
}

const page = (props) => {
    return <AppLayout {...props} />

}

export default Page(connect(state => state)(page));
```

This doesn't work as I'm losing the body of each page using the layout
What am I doing wrong?

The store.js is simply:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers';

export default createStore(reducer);
```

Page is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/store';

const page = (Page) => {
    return (
        class PageWrapper extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <Page />
                    </Provider>
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
export default page;
```

It looks like the store injects itself as props replacing the previous props which had children from each page... which is not great as the previous props are also needed...

Any thoughts would be welcome

Comment: What's `Page`? Otherwise, just `connect(state => state)(AppLayout)` would be enough.

Comment: Page - added the code to the question. This is where the store is loaded.

I need to export the layout - how do you suggest this is done?

Comment: You could remove unnecesary code like `const page ...` wrapper, this component is not doing anything. And `connect(state => state)` the same. It's more clear and easy to understand just `export default Page(connect()(AppLayout))`

Comment: Thanks, but still the same issue - the body of the pages is missing if the store is added, just the footer and the header...

if I do just `export default AppLayout`, the body is fine, if I connect the store, the body disappears... this is because the store messes up the  {this.props.children} which is where the body is passed into...

Comment: Ahhh sure, I can see the issue. Basically you're calling <Page /> component with no `children` props when you define the `const page =` wrapper with `Provider`. Try to init `Provider` with no wrappers, do it directly on AppLayout component

Comment: How can I pass the children props into the Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are not calling the `AppLayout` with childrens. Let me explain:

In your PageWrapper, you define this:

```
const page = (Page) => {
  return (
    class PageWrapper extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Page />  // --> Page does not have children, so, you never gonna see anything
                </Provider>
            )
        }
    }
  )
}
export default page;
```

So, you could do many things to solve this issue, the most easiest is clean the code and you could solve whit this:

```
class AppLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Header />
            {this.props.children}
          <Footer />
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default AppLayout
```

Or just adding render children, like this:

```
const page = (Page) => {
  return (
    class PageWrapper extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Page>
                      { this.props.children }
                    </Page>
                </Provider>
            )
        }
    }
  )
}

export default page;
```

Comment: Just tried the first cleaner version, an error arises:
` Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AppLayout)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(AppLayout) in connect options.`

Comment: Yeah, is my fault, to solve it, just export with no `connect` function

Comment: Works now! Many thanks. I also tried the second option, it didn't work as ReferenceError: props is not defined
I wonder why one doesn't need to connect the store if the provider is there?

Comment: I've edited. Was `this.props` because is inside a class. If my answer was hopeful to you, dont forget to mark as awered